# Cannot find SpriteFont template using MonoGame in Visual Studio 2012 Express (with XNA 4.0)

Tags: visual-studio-2012, xna-4.0, monogame

When I right click Content folder of my project then Add -> new Element, in the dialog box, selecting XNA Game Studio 4.0 I see only 3 templates, which are:

- content type writer
- content processor
- content importer

Since every tutorials that help in creating screen menus say that I should start by loading SpriteFont template, I think that I've missed something.
Any suggestions? Should I give you more informations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to right click your Content project -> add -> new element. If you don't have a Content project  you can create one, just right click on your solution -> add -> new project -> XNA Game Studio 4.0 -> Empty Content Project (4.0)

Comment: sorry dude, I haven't tried yet because I was full of things to do. I'll update you as soon as possible

Answer (score 1):

You have to click the ***solutionname*** Content node and not the ***solutionname*** node. The new items result is based on that.

[image]

In my example, right-clicking the PickingContent node>add new items gave me the correct list.

*And yes, we're probably doing the same tutorial :)*